# Hen voice linked to seeing of Angel?

Tags: reference-request, animals

I have heard that when a donkey cry, it's bad and when hen make sound like it does, it sees a angel? Furthermore it was told that it was told by prophet Muhammad (PUBH). Also I heard that whenever the animals make sound they see unseen like Angel. Is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest hadith:
**إِذَا سَمِعْتُمْ صِيَاحَ الدِّيَكَةِ فَاسْأَلُوا اللَّهَ مِنْ فَضْلِهِ فَإِنَّهَا رَأَتْ مَلَكًا وَإِذَا سَمِعْتُمْ نَهِيقَ الْحِمَارِ فَتَعَوَّذُوا بِاللَّهِ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ الرَّجِيمِ فَإِنَّهُ رَأَى شَيْطَانًا**

**"When you hear the crowing of the roosters, then ask Allah of His bounty, for verily they have seen an angel. When you hear the braying of a donkey, then seek refuge in Allah from Shaitan, for, verily, it has seen a Shaitan."**

[al-Bukhari, Muslim, Abu Dawud, at-Tirmidhi]

There's nothing else authentic about other animals making noises at the sight of an angel.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the Answer of @Sayyid that al-Bukhari has also quoted an other narration in his book al-Adab al Mufrad, which was qualified as sahih adding that if you heard those voices at night (see [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/2312330))

In this book you'll find also ahadith which were qualified as sahih quoting barking of a dog (see for [example](http://sunnah.com/urn/2211890) or [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/2211900) or [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/2211910)) as a sign that they might have seen something which one should seek refuge with Allah from. This is also referred to in a Hadith in [Sunan abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/332).

And Allah knows best!